# Matching multiple strings to a single field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a field in elasticsearch which is defined as an array with the following mapping:

```
"skills":{"type":"text","term_vector": "yes"}
```

It contains an array of multiple skills. Suppose i want to match multiple skills, and check which document contains the skills, how would i do that in a single function?

For example, suppose i need to search for skills such as "python", "ruby" and "C", instead of writing 3 match queries, is there any way it can be combined in 1 query, like the multi_match query which is used to match multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multi_match` isn't helpful here, since what you are searching for is all in the same field.  Assuming you are analyzing with the standard analyzer, or something broadly similar, a simple [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) ought to do the job:

```json
"query": {
    "match" : {
        "skills" : "python ruby c"
    }
}
```

Combining your subqueries using a [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) would be another option.

Comment: But won't that affect the score of the result?

Comment: @KGB - Well, sure. A hit on any of them would contribute to the score. See dis_max if you don't want that.